# Kendo ui Scheduler view date range

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Summary:
How to retrieve start and end date of Scheduler view when navigating to a different day\week, month, etc.

Detail:
When navigating to a new date range in the currently selected view, for purposes of this post the view is displaying by month, I'd like to get the start date and end date of the "next" view.  I would like navigating to a new view to trigger a request to the server for data only within that date range.  We already have a fully developed CRUD, list, search api on front end which we use to plug in to existing Ui components, I would like to use that.  This question has been asked before, but I can't find an answer.  All answers entail tightly coupling the Scheduler to the "transport".

I've used Arshaw and dhtmlx calenders in the past, unless  their api has changed recently, this was a simple task.

For Kendo ui Scheduler
The "navigate" event is called before navigating to next "view" (although I have a work around that I could use here, but not elegant at all).

The "dataBinding" event gets called too often: clicking, draging, etc. (again, I could make a work around her, but again, not elegant).

Others having same issue:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/start-end-date-of-month-view
...but the Telerik repsonse is:
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendoui-scheduler-server-filtering
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/server-filtering
http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-scheduler-view-startdate-and-enddate-in-navigate-event
...but I don't want the widget to have anything to do with data retrieval, I want to detect an event "navigateOnArrival", "viewReady", "viewRendered" or something, then let our data service deal with retrieval, else I'm tightly binding the scheduler to our api.

I'm fairly confident I've missed something simple.
Thanks in advance, all comments gladly welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I fugured out one way and Telerik also provided an answer.

The way I figured out, hook into the "dataBinding" event, eith on your options:

```
yourSched.schedulerOptions = {
views: ["timeline"],  
  dataSource, yourSource,  
  dataBinding: function(e){
      var vw = yourSched.view();
      var startDate = vw.startDate();
      var endDate = vw.endDate();
      if(e.action==="rebind"){   // <<<--------  This gets called once as nav to diff view or date range.
        // Now you can retrieve from server
        myService.getDataFromServer(startDate, endDate)
        .then(function(response){
          ///load etc.
        });
      }
  }
}
```

Telerik also provided a answer:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/scheduler-datasource-refresh-based-on-navigate-date-range#VqcirkrQX0-UK66dHTA0ig

Comment: Brilliant! That was a tremendous help! Thanks so much!